# Large file substring extraction, avoiding line terminators

Tags: java, newline, large-files

The problem is as follows:

Several large files (20+ MB) have got DNA sequences in them. I use following code to connect to those files:

```
fc = FileChannel.open(file);

// Create a read-only CharBuffer on the file
ByteBuffer bbuf = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, 256);
CharBuffer cbuf = Charset.forName("8859_1").newDecoder().decode(bbuf);
```

I know the exact start and ending positions of the subsequence to extract, which would allow me to use the method

```
cbuf.subSequence(start, end);
```

However, the large files have line terminators disrupting the DNA sequence and they count as a character. It's not recommended to assume a fixed width of the lines in the file. What would an efficient way to  'skip over' the line terminators, yet preserve the memory efficiency by using Charbuffer or something similar?

I've tried using greedy quantifiers with regular expressions, but the line terminators disrupt the result yet again. I want to avoid loading in the file contents in its entirety at all costs. Is there no way to treat newline characters as 'non existent'?

Comment: Is memory efficiency really that important? 20 MB isn't that big. How big is the data set in total?

Comment: Is this C/C++ or what language are you using?

Comment: The programming language is Java. Concerning memory efficiency, the processing of the files is just one of several tasks my program must accomplish. If loading in the entire file, what would be the best strategy? Removing all '\n' delimiters seems rather much for the somewhat sparse number of sequences I must extract.

Comment: Doesn't DNA sequences create file that are like a "zillion" bytes? May you should avoid to load the entire file if not needed?

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file, find line terminators and store their position.

Then when extracting, you could converrt position without terminators to real position.

For faster converting, you could precompute offset and then just search for correct offset (O(long n) where n is total ammount of line terminators compared to O(m) where m is ammount of terminators you need to actualy skip)

PS: give some thought to multichar (CR,LF) terminators, if it can happen.

Comment: I've applied this solution, it's likely the best overall. A preprocessing step to extract information, used to speed up sequence extraction in the main search.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't DNA sequences create file that are like a "zillion" (large number of) bytes? Maybe you should avoid to load the entire file if not needed? You seem to have some data (I don't know what data that is; your code doesn't tell) in your variable cbuf. I think you could write a function to remove linebreaks something like:

```
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < cbuf.length; i++)
{
   if(!cbuf[i] != '\n' && cbuf[i] != '\r')
   {
      cbuf[index] = cbuf[i];
      index++; // will only increase if not linebreak
   }
}

int newcbufLength = index + 1;
```

This function will use the original array, so you won't have a new (large?) copy of the data.

(There may be errors as I'm most used to C# and not Java)